# How to bind input form modal using ajax in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to bind edit form modal, I have an edit button 'edit-button" when I click it, an edit modal shown but data returned via route doesn't made.
my ajax code:

```
    var SITEURL = '{{URL::to('')}}';

    $('body').on('click', '#edit-event', function () {
        var event_id = $(this).data('id');
        $.get(SITEURL + '/portal/event/edit/' + event_id, function (data) {
           $('#editHeadingModal').html("Edit Event");
                $('#editEventModal').modal('show');
                $('#event_id').val(data.id);
                $('#title').val(data.title);
                $('#start').val(data.start);
                $('#end').val(data.end);
           })
        });
    })
```

html modal code:

```
div id="editEventModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <form id="event_form" method="POST" action="{{ url('api/update-event/')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="event_id" id="event_id">
            @csrf
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="eventHeadingModal">Edit Event</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">title*</label>
                        <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="start_time">start*</label>
                        <input type="text" id="start" name="start" class="form-control datetime border" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <label for="end_time">end*</label>
                        <input type="text" id="end" name="end" class="form-control datetime" required>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave" value="edit">Edit
                    </button>
                    <a href="{{ route('portal.events.index') }}" class="btn btn-danger">cancel</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I set up bindings when the modal window loads?

Comment: You need to call `$('#editEventModal').modal('show');` after define the all attribute, below this line `$('#end').val(data.end);`

Comment: not worked for me.

Comment: HI, did you check if `data` has correct values ?

Comment: Thanks all, I were had multiple modal, and there is conflict in their ID's, I solved it by rename ID's for each modal.